# Static text in pyopengl

Tags: python, pyopengl

I have a 3d scatter plot using gl.GLScatterPlotItem, but now I want to add text to the window but without it moving with the camera because the current text keep moving whenever i pan around, or if it is possible to add a seperate window maybe to the screen for the text part.

[This is the plot once I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMkrX.png)

[When I moved the plot around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju3WR.png)

So basically I want to set the text to a constant x ,y poisiton independent from the actual plot

Comment: Perhaps some screen shots with indicators drawn onto them for clarity might be a good idea...

Comment: So I have ZERO experience with this library and almost the same amount with python, but I assume you looked at the docs and found no method within this class to do what you are trying to do. It would seem to me that the next place to look is where the graphics are rendered ... some kind of an object that maybe does have methods for adding text as you need it ... In Java I would be looking at Pane classes in my scene, but I don't know how Python handles that ... just food for thought while we wait for someone smarter than me to comment. :-)

Comment: It looks like that whole library renders into a GraphicsScene class??? If that is the case, maybe you can reference that parent class and add a label into it in real-time? Im just looking at the java docs and taking educated stabs here ... I might be out in left field, i don't know.